# How to set up Bootstrap in Django

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, static

I am learning how to develop in Django and I have a simple website up and running on manage.py runserver.
I am trying to set up Bootstrap on it but I cant seem to pull my Bootstrap files into my html template page.
I have my template in ContainerFolder\homeapp\templates\homeapp\index.html.
I have put the BootStrap files in a toplevel static folder ie in ContainerFolder\Static because I want to avail them to all apps.
I have set up my settings file as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MAIN_PROJECT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(MAIN_PROJECT, 'static/'),
)
```

My template header is as follows, the html in the body simply shows with no formatting:
Can anyone kindly advise me on how to fix this, any assistance highly appreciated:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Clean Blog</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{% static "/css/clean-blog.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: Does it work if you drop the leading slash - ie `{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you have an extra **/** that you don't need just before your css.

typically the best way to debug this sort of thing is to view your page in a browser, view source on the html page and see what path your css files are pointing to, does this path match your folder structure?

Comment: Yes, that has sorted the issue, thank you! I had checked the html source but it was showing up as <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> with no indication of the static value, I guess Django does not parse a template tag value if there is an error. Thank you for the quick answer